# Access subset array with foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i have arrays like this

Any idea how to access `#items` subset with `foreach` or somthing fast like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [#theme] => item_list
            [#items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [nid] => 1
                        [changed] => 1514034947
                        [title] => TITLE 1
                    )

                    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [nid] => 2
                        [changed] => 1514034947
                        [title] => TITLE 2
                    )

                )
        )


     [1] => Array
       (
          [#theme] => pager
       )
```

**BEST**

Comment: Did you changed the original object ?

Comment: @user2486 A little

Comment: First debug like echo "<pre>"; print_r($array[0]['#items']); And then use foreach like foreach( $array[0]['#items'] as $item )

Comment: You can also use count like $noofarray = count($array); to loop through all your elements in while loop and then foreach.

Comment: This question is unclear.  What code have you tried?  What exactly is going to be done with this data?  Will a `#items` key exist in every subarray?  Please improve your question.

Comment: We need to see a suitable representation of your input array, your failed coding attempt, and your expected result -- if you want to receive the best possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your elements are located below 3 levels so you need to use foreach thrice like below:

```
foreach($data as $items_list){
    foreach($items_list[#items] as $items){
        foreach($items as $val){
            echo $val['nid'];
        }
    }
}
```

You can simply count array everytime and add condition before foreach loop to check if further array exists or not.

Like you can count main array and add condition with while loop and then use foreach like below:

```
$count = 0;
while($count<count($array)){
    foreach($array[$count]['#items'] as $items ){
        foreach($items as $val){
            echo $val['nid'];
        }
    }
$count = $count+1;
}
```

Before doing anything, its better if you debug your multiple arrays like below:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); die;
```

Comment: This way is faster, thanks

Comment: Thanks! Please try once and let me know if any issue comes

Comment: But suggest if you want to use a nested one than mine is way faster then this one...because of number of loop and also there a for each loop always better one if you want to traverse an array.

Comment: Calling `count ()` on every iteration is NEVER going to be the fastest way.

Comment: Yes there are many more solutions but I have given the one that comes in my mind. @mickmackusa Sir I know you have many as you are having better experience. Count() is just used for counting the array every time before proceeding and nothing else.

Comment: In my case ` foreach( $output[0]['#items'] as $item )
    {
  print_r ($item);
    }` I guess fastest way...

Comment: @mickmackusa Sir thanks for your advice.

Comment: @BijanZand You can check the one that resolves your issue my dear friend :)

Comment: nested foreach so slow !!

Comment: @Bijan Your line of code may be the best way, but because your question was unclear, everyone had to guess what was best for your task.  Please improve your question to add the details as I have requested - this is a requirement of all questions on SO.

Comment: We all are here to learn and slowly improve. Happy coding to all! Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array structure is exactly as you posted here is something you can experiment with. I don't know what you want to do with each item so this example just prints out the elements of each one:

```
foreach( $array as $outerarray )
{
    foreach( $outerarray['#items'] as $item ) 
    {
        echo "{$item['nid']} {$item['changed']} {$item['title']}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @C_Miller this will work only for the first item of an array fails if have multiples...

Comment: Addy is right. Updating. There was only one item originally, but question was edited.

Comment: this also heaving the same issue you have to use a nested array or vector mapping for the same ...or this gonna work with only one first item.you need to change the `$array[0]['#items']` to something like `$array[i]['#items']`.

Comment: The problem also is I don't know if there is going to be an #items in each array element. In his example there is not. Which would the require an extra check in the loop if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `foreach` to get the final item list from this array object...

```
    foreach($data as $items_list)
    {
        foreach($items_list[#items] as $items)
        {
           // do something here....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which way is faster??

Comment: there must be a use of object you want. If there only one time you using this item then use the direct mapping or if you want to work with each item that can be followed...

Comment: yes, of course, the direct mapping is much faster than the loop but not work
 with multiple items...

Comment: So finally your solution use nested foreach yeah ?

Comment: Yep! depends... I just try to explain your need and provide the best solution for you.